# Android/Gradle espresso test not starting activity

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-espresso

I'm having difficulty convincing the new Android build system to run tests.  When running the test it gives the `Unable to resolve activity for: Intent` error which has been discussed in other questions but there is nothing in there which have fixed my problem.

I've stripped it down so that my test package does not rely on my main package (`com.wealdtech.app`) at all but still have the problem starting activity.

My test activity:

```
package com.wealdtech.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class TileLayoutTestActivity extends Activity
{
  @Override
  public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  }
}
```

And my test class:

```
package com.wealdtech.test;

import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;

public class TileLayoutTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<TileLayoutTestActivity>
{
  public TileLayoutTest()
  {
    super(TileLayoutTestActivity.class);
  }

  @Override
  protected void setUp() throws Exception
  {
    super.setUp();
    setActivityInitialTouchMode(false);
  }

  public void testNull()
  {
    final TileLayoutTestActivity activity = getActivity();
    activity.finish();
  }
```

Relevant parts of build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 19
  buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
  }

  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 19

    testPackageName "com.wealdtech.test"
    testInstrumentationRunner "com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner"
  }
}
```

The full stack trace I obtain is:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not launch activity
at com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentation.startActivitySync(GoogleInstrumentation.java:286)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.launchActivityWithIntent(InstrumentationTestCase.java:119)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.launchActivity(InstrumentationTestCase.java:97)
at android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.getActivity(ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.java:104)
at com.wealdtech.test.TileLayoutTest.testNull(TileLayoutTest.java:21)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:214)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:199)
at android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.runTest(ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.java:192)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:554)
at com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner.java:167)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1701)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve activity for: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x14000000 cmp=com.wealdtech.test/.TileLayoutTestActivity }
at android.app.Instrumentation.startActivitySync(Instrumentation.java:379)
at com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentation.access$101(GoogleInstrumentation.java:52)
at com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentation$2.call(GoogleInstrumentation.java:268)
at com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentation$2.call(GoogleInstrumentation.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

I haven't included my `AndroidManifest.xml` because everything I read suggests that I do not need to add an intent for `TileLayoutTestActivity`, however I have tried to do this anyway and ended up with the same result.

I have also tried changing the Gradle plugin from `android-library` to `android` in case that was causing the problem, but again the same result.

I can't see any documentation regarding prerequisites for Espresso testing, or testing with the Gradle build system, which I haven't already covered.  Any ideas as to which I cannot start the activity as part of the test?

Comment: Were you able to find a fix for this? Running into the same issue on my project.

Comment: any one has a solution?

Answer (score 4):

For a project that uses the `android-library` plugin, it's semi-accurate to say that the `AndroidManifest.xml` isn't really used. In fact all a library project's manifest needs to compile is this:

```
<manifest package="com.package.yours"/>
```

Any permissions or intents you try to put in it will be ignored when the your AAR file is created. It being a library, and as near as I can tell, nothing in the library project's manifest makes it into the AAR (or JAR if you're making one of those too).

But! That *is* the manifest that's going to be used when you build a test project that gets pushed to a device. You can literally dump gibberish in `src/androidTest/AndroidManifest.xml` and gradle won't care, but you have to add your test activity to `src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` or else `./gradlew connectedCheck` is going to throw runtime exceptions.

My project looks like this (it really does, I only changed the names):

```
src/
  androidTest/
    java/
      com.package.mine/
        TestActivity.java
        VariousTests.java
  main/
    java/
      com.package.mine/
        FancyLibrary.java
    AndroidManifest.xml
```

And here is my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.uie.uieanalytics">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PERM_I_NEED"/>

    <application>
        <activity android:name=".TestActivity" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Otherwise, I'm using the same test runner as you, and my `build.gradle` is similar enough.

Comment: What's annoying is that AS doesn't seem to pick up on the fact that the classes exist and they show up as red. Thanks for the answer though!

Answer (score 4):

*Reference for others who can come to this post as I came, so they don't lose the time.*

1. change from legacy, abandoned, ugly ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 to **annotations** which is supported by AndroidStudio, Gradle and Espresso 2. This will be developed by Google further.
2. forget about that ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 forever!
3. start using **@RunWith**, **@LargeTest**, **@Test**, **@Rule** ...

Answer (score 3):

For instrumentation tests Android builds two APK's - one with the app and one with the tests. If you put activity to `androidTest` flavour, then it belongs to the test APK. If you start an activity using instrumentation (either directly or by using `ActivityTestRule`) later on, then Android searches for it in your app APK and fails, because there is no such activity in the app APK.

To solve the problem you can define a test activity (class and manifest) in the `debug` flavour of your app. Then it will be packed with your app APK and tests will work just fine.

**Update:** or - as Austyn Mahoney suggested - you should use `InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getTargetContex‌​t()` to access the app context instead of instrumentation one.

Comment: You don't have to define the Activity in your test package, you just need to use the correct `Context` when creating the your Intent. Use `InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext()` This will return the app `Context` rather than the instrumentation apk's `Context`.

Answer (score 1):

Kindly change activity name inside Rule that u can able to run

ActivityTestRule mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(
            change activity name)